# How to set a default/fixed value for a complex type element?

Tags: xml, xsd

```
<xsd:element name="category">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:simpleContent>
        <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
          <xsd:attribute default="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next" ref="soapenv:actor" use="optional"/>
          <xsd:attribute ref="soapenv:mustUnderstand" use="optional"/>
        </xsd:extension>
      </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

The element name is “category” and I want it to always be defaulted to the value “ABC”

The above definition generates the element in Soap UI as follows:

```
<urn:category soapenv:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next" soapenv:mustUnderstand="?">?</urn:category>
```

What I need is that the element should get generated as

```
<urn:category soapenv:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next" soapenv:mustUnderstand="?">ABC</urn:category>
```

To achieve this, I tried

1. `<xsd:element name="category" fixed="ABC">`
2. `<xsd:element name="category" default="ABC">`

None of the above was able to generate the element with the value

Am I doing something wrong here? Please help.

Thanks.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

From the XSD point of view, the ways you have tried to specify a default or fixed value are the correct ways, and they seem to work fine to me.  That is, if I create a schema document containing the element declaration you give, with the additional attribute `fixed="ABC"` on the `xsd:element` element, then the document `<category>ABC</category>` is valid against the schema and the document `<category>abc</category>` is not, and elicits a complaint about the value not matching the required value 'ABC'.

To be painfully explicit, this is the full schema document I used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:soapenv="http://example.com/soapenv"
  elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xsd:import namespace="http://example.com/soapenv"
  schemaLocation="complex-default.2.xsd"/>

  <xsd:element name="category" fixed="ABC">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:simpleContent>
        <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
          <xsd:attribute 
            default="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next"
            ref="soapenv:actor" 
            use="optional"/>
          <xsd:attribute ref="soapenv:mustUnderstand" 
            use="optional"/>
        </xsd:extension>
      </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

Note that the namespace name for the soapenv prefix is one I made up; the schema document `complex-default.2.xsd` referred to for that namespace is a simple placeholder designed to supply unconstraining definitions of the two attributes in the namespace used in your schema fragment:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://example.com/soapenv"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"> 
  <xs:attribute name="actor" type="xs:anyURI"/>
  <xs:attribute name="mustUnderstand" type="xs:boolean"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Perhaps the problem is with your SOAP tool, and not with your XSD schema document.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This thing works for a simple element. However, in my case the element is a complexType with simpleContent. Could you please paste here the the entire definition of the element which worked for you.